# Ações diferentes, mas, totalmente relacionadas?

Tags: debate

Só queria entender ou alertar do porque um resposta que tem **4 votos negativos** só tem **2 votos de fechamento**, embora sejam ações diferentes são totalmente relacionadas?

Também será que as pessoas que votaram negativos são votos em manada e não entendem o funcionamento do site?

Estou no site há algum tempo e nesses últimos meses percebo que várias perguntas estão ainda em aberto mesmo tendo votos negativos ou nenhuma interação, tem alguma forma (eu acho que é sinalização, mas, isso nunca funciona) para que essas perguntas sejam fechadas?

Comment: Pode ser "voto de manada", mas também pode ser de pessoas que ainda não tem pontos suficientes para dar voto de fechamento (já que precisa de só 125 pra poder votar negativo, mas 3000 pra votar pra fechar). E muitas perguntas não são fechadas porque - na minha opinião - falta gente pra fechar tanta coisa: apenas cerca de [300 usuários](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/526/alltime/pt-stackoverflow) tem mais de 3000 pontos, e se contar só quem acessou neste mês, dá [cerca de 20](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/edit/1326545#resultSets). E desses, tem vários que quase nunca fecham nada...

Comment: É esse pode ser sim um dos problemas. @hkotsubo ...

Answer (score 7):

Fechamento e negativo não são relacionados. Eu mesmo tendo a não negativar o que fecho e não fecho o que negativo, mas tem exceções, quando é algo realmente bem problemático.

Nada impede de ter qualquer combinação de negativos ou votos de fechamento, cada caso é um caso. E claro a comunidade pode estar agindo de forma equivocada dentro da filosofia do site. Ou pode ser que esteja fazendo certo nos mesmo critérios e alguém discorde. Por isso eu gosto de consultar outras pessoas em muitos casos que não são tão óbvios, pena que todo mundo tá de "saco cheio" e sinto que nem posso fazer tanto quanto fazia no passado, sob pena de atazanar mais ainda as pessoas. E de fato ando ficando sem resposta ou sempre as mesmas "2 ou 3" pessoas que respondem.

Não posso dizer como as pessoas votam porque cada pessoa é diferente e não estou na cabeça delas.

O que eu percebo é que muitas pessoas preferem negativar do que fechar para seu nome não ficar vinculado à ação e sofrer retaliação, cobrança ou ter outros problemas. Então hoje o fechamento ficou quase todo nas costas da moderação diamante, pelo menos para finalizar.

Se ficar lá negativado sem respostas ou com respostas sem votos ou negativadas vai acabar sumindo do site por ação do sistema. Para mim resolve o problema. O problema é quando há uma resposta ruim (em perguntas ruins é quase certo que a resposta será ruim, por mais que o autor da resposta tenha se esforçado) e positivada, porque aí perpetua o conteúdo. Esse é o problema do site.

Fechar ajuda não ter respostas ruins, mas não ajuda eliminar conteúdo ruim positivado.

Eu só poderia repetir o que falo há muito tempo, a comunidade precisa participar mais dos fechamentos. Mas não posso exigir de ninguém, não vou criticar que não o faz, consigo entender porque não acontece.

Poucas pessoas fazem sua parte e algumas deturpam completamente o site. Tem gente que nem causa encrenca, mas age completamente à parte como só existisse essa pessoa no site. Só que ela não faz nada que mereça punição. Eventualmente toma negativo por algo errado, mas ela aprendeu até se proteger disso respondendo sem dar resposta.

Algumas pessoas decidiram que não vão fechar nada. Outras participam só em alguns casos bem específicos. Não vou criticar que fez essas opções, mas alguma pessoas deveriam fazer mais se realmente importa-se com o site.

Detalhes matemáticos foram dados pelo hkotsubo em comentário acima.

O que eu posso dizer é que eu não consigo cuidar de todos detalhes do site. E curiosamente sou acusado de fazer muito mais do que deveria, então nunca vou agradar todo mundo.

E posso dizer que a sinalização posso ajudar em casos que o fechamento for muito importante. A sinalização sempre funciona se tiver sentido. Quase todas sinalizações são aceitas. Se não foi é porque ela foi considerada errada. Algumas pessoas, mesmo depois de muito tempo, não entenderam como o site funciona. Não vou falar especificamente de qualquer usuário, mas alguns usuários quase nunca sinalizam. Sinalização não mandada nunca será atendida.

Vou aproveitar a oportunidade para dizer que andei participando de discussões sobre o SOpt em outros locais, alguns recentes e cada vez estou mais convencido que algumas pessoas que poderíamos chamar de "externas" entendem e valorizam o que tentamos fazer aqui e outros só são detratores. Dá pra perceber o nível do debate de cada grupo. Não vale a pena atender a demanda do grupo que quer tudo livre, elas não vão a lugar algum, é melhor fazer o que precisa ser feito porque agrada quem merece.

Comment: *Quase todas sinalizações são aceitas. Se não foi é porque ela foi considerada errada* Isso não acontece assim como está escrito e está errado, eu já passei no site em sinalizar pergunta e essa pergunta ser recusada na sinalização e depois a pergunta é fechada por um moderador, são coisas que eu realmente fico sem entender. A outra parte do seu texto parece um desabafo parece um loop sem fim esse tipo de situação onde parece que existam forças inversas acontecendo aqui e é preocupante, muitos usuários bom saíram, e outras estão no site e não ligam mais ... é preocupante.

Comment: Sua afirmação não faz sentido. O sue problema é sempre achar que tudo o que você faz está certo e tudo o que os outros fazem está errado. Você não pode fazer a afirmação que fez, você não tem dados para isso, é só um especulação baseado em crenças suas. Talvez as suas sinalizações sejam das poucas que são recusadas. Eu digo talvez porque eu nem medi isso, nem eu posso afirmar isso tendo acesso às informações, imagina quem não tem. Sem um caso concreto não dá para discutir. Quando tiver um poste, caso contrário isso é improdutivo.

Comment: Eu não preocupo mais com a situação do site, eu fiz o que eu podia, e faço o que ainda dá, mas se alguém quer melhoras, pode fazer, sempre disse isso. Agora o site é o que é. Eu continuarei fazendo minha parte, se não é suficiente, todos tem direito de fazer mais.

Comment: Talvez o problema de achar o que eu faço é tudo certo não seja exatamente eu ... mas, tudo bem ... e eu posso afirmar sim que as sinalização aconteceu isso porque realmente aconteceu ... não só sou eu quem falo é outras pessoas também, mas, eu não posso falar pelos demais ...

Comment: Pode achar o que quiser, afirmar precisa de provas. O Trump acha que venceu a eleição. Só porque a pessoa acha não torna verdade. Quando apresentar o caso concreto dá para discutir, caso contrário nem argumento isso é.

Comment: E esse vitimíssimo de achar que você não faz o máximo, é uma falácia sua todo mundo sabe que você ainda faz bastante coisa, esse texto não é ideal e não cola para a sua pessoa ... é só ver os números

Comment: O que haver politica com o site! desastroso ...

Comment: Eu fiz o máximo que pude, e continuo fazendo tudo o que posso dentro das circunstâncias atuais.

Comment: Eu acho que isso é outra falácia: ***Eu não preocupo mais com a situação do site,*** se isso fosse real, você não faria a sua parte como você mesmo falou

Comment: Preocupação é um estado de espírito, você sabe mais que eu do meu estado de espírito. Eu dei uma olhada nas estatísticas de suas sinalizações. A esmagadora maioria foi aceita (e não foram tantas assim). Das rejeitadas, a maioria foi pela comunidade, quase todas rejeitadas pela moderação e foram poucas, é de "não é uma resposta" que é o erro mais comum que as pessoas cometem em sinalização, já que uma resposta errada ainda é uma resposta. Se tiver mais rejeições pode ser em outra conta, Se tiver outras favor informar quais são. Não posso dar mais detalhes sem autorização do usuário.

Comment: Eu sou tenho uma conta! #filosofia

Comment: @novic, veja [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247658/608272) as sinalizações de *qualidade muito baixa* e *não é uma resposta* no Stack Overflow em Português só entram na fila do moderador uma hora após sinalizadas. O objetivo desse atraso é dar primeiro à comunidade a chance de lidar com esses sinalizadores...

Comment: ...Então aqui em *...eu já passei no site em sinalizar pergunta e essa pergunta ser recusada na sinalização e depois a pergunta é fechada por um moderador...* onde parece ser centro da discordância, veja que a todos usuários é concreta a hipótese de ter suas sinalizações rejeitada pela comunidade e posterior a rejeição um moderador encontrar a pergunta e fechar.

Comment: Nesse caso @AugustoVasques a duas ações tem o mesmo objeto, enfim está lá no meu usuário um dos exemplos precitados e não vou a partir desse momento ficar discutindo, não vai adiantar muito isso aqui.